# Android app claims I have no activity

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

[image: Android mobile screenshot]

Could the active developers please activate the "activity" tab, so I can actively view my activity? Perhaps you can partake in the activity of bug-fixing action, maybe by creating an Android `Activity` or actively activating your bug-deactivating skills? Not to be an activist, but I prefer not to act as though I actually have no activity at all.

Comment: Actual apologies for the lack of freehand red circle action, but I am currently acting from my web-activated mobile device, so I can't actually activate the action of FHRCs.

Comment: -1: not enough freehand circles. Slacker!

Comment: I can see my activity just fine; maybe you had a network interruption of some sort?

Comment: @Raff Nah, this has been happening for at least a week now, both on Wi-Fi and 4G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) because they're back now.  Could have been an intermittent issue or a bug long since fixed.